# What is a reliable way to change and then unchange the locale in R?

Tags: r, locale

Within a function, I want to change the locale, do some stuff, then unchange it.  Because side effects are bad.

```
old_locale <- Sys.getlocale()

# do some stuff

Sys.setlocale(old_locale)
```

However, `Sys.setlocale` requires a `category` and `locale` argument.

On the other hand, `Sys.getlocale()` gives me this:

```
"LC_COLLATE=English_Australia.1252;LC_CTYPE=English_Australia.1252;LC_MONETARY=English_Australia.1252;LC_NUMERIC=C;LC_TIME=English_Australia.1252"
```

Ok.  I can probably deal with this:

```
old_locale <- Sys.getlocale()
locale_key_values <- strsplit(strsplit(old_locale, ';')[[1]], '=')[[1]], '=')
locale_keys <- lapply(locale_key_values, getElement, name=1)
locale_values <- lapply(locale_key_values, getElement, name=2)

# do some stuff

mapply(Sys.setlocale, category=locale_keys, locale=locale_values)
```

Problem solved!

...or is it?

```
Sys.setlocale(locale='C')
```

`Sys.getlocale()` now returns `"C"`!  That's not going to work with my key-value parser above.

And I suddenly realise that I don't know anything about locales or the range of strings that `Sys.getlocale()` might return.

Does anyone know of a reliable way to save and restore locale state?

Comment: Clever idea, I wish it were that easy!  Sys.setlocale takes exactly two arguments, a category and a locale.  It won't accept for example an LC_MONETARY argument.  I get the following error when running your code:  `Error in (function (category = "LC_ALL", locale = "")  : 
  unused arguments ("LC_MONETARY=English_Australia.1252", "LC_NUMERIC=C", "LC_TIME=English_Australia.1252")`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`?Sys.getlocale` says:

> For `category = "LC_ALL"` the details of the string are system-specific:
>   it might be a single locale name or a set of locale names separated by
>   `"/"` (Solaris, OS X) or `";"` (Windows, Linux).  For portability, it is
>   best to query categories individually: it is not necessarily the case
>   that the result of `foo <- Sys.getlocale()` can be used in
>   `Sys.setlocale("LC_ALL", locale = foo)`.

So you need to do something like:

```
localeCategories <- c("LC_COLLATE","LC_CTYPE","LC_MONETARY","LC_NUMERIC","LC_TIME")
locales <- setNames(lapply(localeCategories, Sys.getlocale), localeCategories)
```

Better yet, you should determine which locale setting(s) you need to change, and only change the one(s) you need to. For example, you might only need to change LC_TIME if you're parsing date-time character strings, or you might only need to change LC_COLLATE if you need to change the character string collation order.